# Unexpected identifier when trying to include `attach: function` in a Drupal JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7

I am new to Drupal and am following a tutorial to add some JQuery to a module's existing .js file.

Currently, the module's .js file looks kind of like this:

```
(function($, Drupal, google, window, document, undefined) {
  Drupal.behaviors.moduleName = {
   map: null,
   stores: [],
   markers: [],
   attach: function(context, settings) {
     //EXISTING FUNCTION THAT DOES SOMETHING
   }
}
```

All I want to do is add:

```
attach: function(context, settings) {
  console.log("Hello world");
};
```

as a proof of concept.

I've added this directory below the existing function, but when I refresh the page breaks and I get an error in my console:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

pointing to the line where I've added my function.

Would anyone know the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to close the first parentheses. Additionally, I think you are trying to write an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), so if that is the case, you would need to call the function as well. Try this:

```
(function($, Drupal, google, window, document, undefined) {
  Drupal.behaviors.moduleName = {
   map: null,
   stores: [],
   markers: [],
   attach: function(context, settings) {
     //EXISTING FUNCTION THAT DOES SOMETHING
   }
})(); // I added a )(); here
```